# SLIM framework keeps giving me 404

Tags: php, slim

I have just started using Slim framework (http://www.slimframework.com/); I have downloaded the zip file from the same site which has some examples and to test it I tried localhost/proj1 and it works but when I try localhost/proj1/index.php/delete it keeps me giving me 404 error, although it is supposed to echo out "This is a DELETE route", if I'm right!

```
$app->delete(
    '/delete',
    function () {
        echo 'This is a DELETE route';
    }
);
```

am I doing something wrong?

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Is your .htaccess set up properly?

Comment: the code that already included the htaccess; please see my updated question

Comment: Are you [calling your URI](http://docs.slimframework.com/#DELETE-Routes) with a `DELETE` [request method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_method#Request_methods)?

Comment: this is what I'm calling : localhost/proj1/index.php/delete

Comment: Yes, I've read that. But with which request method? Probably `GET`, thats why its not working... You've defined a `DELETE` route. Please read the [docs](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Routing) again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be pointing your browser to:-

```
localhost/proj1/delete
```

And your code should be:-

```
$app->get('/delete',
 function(){
        echo 'This is a DELETE route';
    }
);
```

As your browser will be sending a 'get' request, not a 'delete' request. Your original code would work if your browser sent a 'delete' request, but it can't. See [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/211790) to find out why.

Comment: still it gives me 404